# Is it possible to programmatically set the start background?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, windows-phone, windows-phone-8.1

Is it possible to set the start background image using the Windows Phone 8.1 SDK? After extensive Googling, I have found nothing, which does not look promising. You would think this would have been announced somewhere. However, I wanted to confirm that it is not possible before giving up.

Comment: Not sure why this should be closed for "unclear what you're asking". In my mind my the question seems pretty clear.

Comment: Would you find "yes" or "no" to be a useful answer?  Likely what you want to know is "how"--in which case you should detail what you've tried and why it has failed.  Just a simple search should have pointed you at something like: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3595120/how-can-i-programatically-set-the-lock-screen-image-in-windows-phone-7

Comment: Yes. I would find yes or no useful. Also, that question you linked to has absolutely nothing to do with what I asked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not possible, never announced, no method in SDK.